# Jquery, tranfer value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code to transfer value which is inputed in input box to span:

```
$(function()  {
     $(".single-product p:nth-child(5) input").keyup(function () {
  $('#birthdate').html($(this).val());
});
 });
```

and it works but when I use it with another function which I made for a jquery datepicker (calendar)

```
 $(function() {
        $( ".single-product p:nth-child(5) input" ).datepicker();
      });
```

It does not transfer value to a span until I press enter. How can I change this to be automatic? (As soon as a user picks the date it goes to input (currently works) and then to span.

Comment: Did you tryied to attach the event [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to your datepicker ?

Comment: Good tip. Works! Post as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onSelect()` event of datepicker

```
$( ".single-product p:nth-child(5) input" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
         //set value to another input
      }
   });
```

Comment: Yes great this is also an option.

Comment: @MarcSommerson. this is more dynamic